# C# value type parameter copy thread safety

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Assuming I have a certain `struct`:

```
struct Foo{}
```

that has been allocated on the heap (as a `class` member), and I have a number of threads that read and write to that `struct`.
If I pass the variable to a certain function:

```
void Bar(Foo param);
```

param will be a copy of that `struct`.
Is the copy operation itself thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Never assume any operation is thread-safe by default - as it isn't.***

For example consider the following `Types`:

```
public class A
{
    public B b;
}

public struct B
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public int d;
}
```

and the following method:

```
public static void Func(B b)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{b.a}, {b.b}, {b.c}, {b.d}");
}
```

If you will have the following `Main` method and pause the console once a while:

```
A a = new A();
new Thread(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        a.b.a = 5;
        a.b.b = 5;
        a.b.c = 5;
        a.b.d = 5;
    }
}).Start();
while (true)
{
    a.b.a = 1;
    a.b.b = 2;
    a.b.c = 3;
    a.b.d = 4;
    Func(a.b);
}
```

you will see that some of the `structs` are mixed between `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`.

Any primitive operation on a type greater than 32 bit is not atomic on a `x86` machine, same with 64 bit and `x64`.

Not that this means you can use any operation on an `int` will be safe, for example:

Manipulating an `int` from a multi-core processor, let's say, `++someInt` from 2 threads, even if it compiles to `inc` `x86` instruction, the following can happen.

- `someInt` is 9.
- core 1 takes `someInt` from its cache.
- core 2 takes `someInt` from the cache.
- core 1 increases the value it has to 10 and saves it to the cache.
- core 2 increases the value it has to 10 and saves it to the cache.

`someInt` was increased twice, yet it's equals to 10.

Using `Interlocked` instead for example will compile to `lock inc` which will lock the bus and ensure that the core has exclusive ownership of the relevant cache.

Comment: Downvoter please explain so I can improve my answer.

Comment: I agree. I have a downvote too, with no argument against. We may be wrong, but that should be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Copy operation is not thread safe for anything larger than `int` (which is fetched at once and therefore nothing can interfere with its value).

If you take anything larger than 4 bytes, then it is possible that the value would be fetched 4-by-4 bytes and in between those operations another thread might change parts of the value.

For example, loading `long` is not thread safe because on a 32-bit machine another thread could write it over, and then you would read one half old value and another half new value.

All this stands for structs as well if they take more than 4 bytes.

Comment: It's valid to consider 64-bit copies threadsafe in cases where you know the code will only run on 64-bit processes, e.g. the library is 64-bit only, or you're taking a 64-bit only fastpath having detected that the code is running in a 64-bit process.

Comment: Conversely, even 32-bit copies aren't threadsafe if not 32-bit aligned, though that will never apply to parameter copies

Comment: That assumes you know that the code will be compiled as 64-bit. Since that is controlled by a compiler switch, I wouldn't recommend to rely on it.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat I hope you know the question is about the runtime taking the struct value and copying it and sending its copy to the target method.

Comment: @JonHanna "The runtime guarantees that a type whose size is no bigger than a native (pointer-size) integer will not be read or written partially." - from Essential C# by Mark Michaelis. This implies that all values are aligned to 4 byte addresses.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes, I'm talking about copying structures (and all other value types, including integers and longs). Runtime works the same for all value types. The point is that structs larger than native pointer size may take more than one step to copy and therefore are not atomic, i.e. they are not thread safe.